# How to print the next value in the line that contains the maximum of a column?

Tags: awk

How to print the next value in the line that contains the maximum of a column?

```
for f in a*; do 
    awk 'BEGIN{a=   0}{if ($2>0+a) a=$2}{if($2 = a) b=$1} END{print FILENAME, b}' "$f"
done
```

a*

```
4 5
6 6
5 5.5
7 55
```

desired result

```
a45 7
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your code? `if($2 = a)` (assignment) should presumably be `if($2 == a)` (comparison)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: How is the expected output of `a45 7` derived from your sample input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this depending on whether you'd want the first or last value printed for duplicate key fields is this to print the last one:

```
awk 'NR==1{max=$2} $2>=max{max=$2; val=$1} END{print FILENAME, val}' "$f"
```

or this to print the first one:

```
awk 'NR==1{max=$2; val=$1} $2>max{max=$2; val=$1} END{print FILENAME, val}' "$f"
```